# Installing certs? Have i done this right?

Tags: iphone, xcode, key, keychain

I'm following a guide, which says this:

Once the cert if approved you can go download and install the cert under the Certificates menu.
Once your certs are in place you need to add your device to the list of “Devices”.

When i double clicked the cert file, it added itself to keychain access like so:
[image]

Should it appear under both private key and public key, and if so, how do i get it to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Double clicking should do it. Mine looks just like yours and I've built many apps to devices and uploaded a couple to the app store as well so I think you're fine.